# Using pytest to test django packages

Tags: django, pytest, django-apps, pytest-django

I have created a Django package (a Django App) that adds functionality to Django when installed and referenced in `settings.py` `INSTALLED_APPS` of the Django project.

I am familiar with writing tests for Django using pytest, and the pytest-django plugin. As the pytest-django plugin provide fixtures such as a web client to interact with the django project. However I never wrote tests for a Django package.

How do I use pytest and pytest-django plugin to test my Django package, without having a real django project that has settings.py that loads the package?